# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop(Don't use useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toast, storybook, rerender

This code is said to cause a lot of re-renders. What is the problem?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Toast, ToastProps } from './Toast';

  const [list, setList] = useState<ToastProps[]>([
    { title: '제목', message: 'Message', type: 'GREEN' },
    { title: '오류', message: 'Message', type: 'RED' },
  ]);
  let toastProperties = null;

  const AddToast = (
    title: string,
    message: string,
    type: 'GREEN' | 'RED' | 'YELLOW' | 'BLUE'
  ) => {
    toastProperties = {
      id: list.length + 1,
      type,
      title,
      message,
    };
    setList([...list, toastProperties]);
  };

  AddToast('제목', '메세지', 'BLUE');

  return (
    <_Container>
      {list.map((list) => {
        const { title, message, type } = list;
        return <Toast type={type} title={title} message={message}></Toast>;
      })}
    </_Container>
  );
};
```

I tried to use useEffect to resolve this error, but the animation was initialized and was unable to write. Toast has an animation so I think it occured. Please solve this problem.

Comment: A better question here would be why not just add it initially to the `useState` hook, especially since you already do this with some other values ('RED' / 'GREEN'). Also, why do you have `id` in each toast you add but not for the initial ones? Seems like an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

This is being called on every render:

```
AddToast('제목', '메세지', 'BLUE');
```

When you call that function, it internally updates state.  Updating state triggers a re-render.  The re-render calls that function again.  Which updates state again.  Etc.  Etc.

If you want this to happen only on the initial render of the component, use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  AddToast('제목', '메세지', 'BLUE');
}, []);
```

An empty dependency array will invoke the operation only when the component is first loaded.  No dependency array at all will invoke the operation on every render.  And anything in the dependency array would invoke the operation when those dependencies have changed.

Comment: I tried as it is and there is no problem. Thank you for your answer. I came to realize about re-rendering.